Sedona Rtree spatial index construction time
By executing the following code in Sedona Context, I get the respective messages in the log of the spark job. In the job, I am handling two SpatialRDDs (objectRDDA and objectRDDB). I choose to partition the objectRDDA based on QuadTree, and then by using its schema, I continue with the partitioning of objectRDDB. Then, I build an RTree index per partition for the objectRDDB, for executing subsequently a spatial join operation.
The log file, contains totally three stages, with IDs 4, 5 and 6. It seems that the 4 and 5 stages run at the same time, and concern to the parititioning/shuffling of the data of objectRDDA and objectRDDB (the respective tasks are referred as "ShuffleTaskMap").
Stage 6 has to do with the computation of the spatial join. The tasks under this stage are referred as "ResultTask". Does this stage cover the construction of the RTree locally in each partition? Or does stage 6 cover exclusively the processing for the calculation of the spatial join after the RTrees have been built?
        objectRDDA.spatialPartitioning(GridType.QUADTREE);
        objectRDDB.spatialPartitioning(objectRDDA.getPartitioner());

        objectRDDB.buildIndex(IndexType.RTREE, true);
        cou = JoinQuery.SpatialJoinQueryFlat(objectRDDB, objectRDDA, true, SpatialPredicate.INTERSECTS).count();

Log file:
{"Event":"SparkListenerJobEnd","Job ID":3,"Completion Time":1725739161662,"Job Result":{"Result":"JobSucceeded"}}
{"Event":"SparkListenerJobStart","Job ID":4,"Submission Time":1725739161772,"Stage Infos":[{"Stage ID":5,"Stage Attempt ID":0,"Stage Name":"flatMapToPair at SpatialRDD.java:325","Number of Tasks":5,"RDD Info":[{"RDD ID":11,"Name":"MapPartitionsRDD","Scope":"{\"id\":\"22\",\"name\":\"flatMap\"}","Callsite":"flatMapToPair at SpatialRDD.java:325","Parent IDs":[5],"Storage Level":{"Use Disk":false,"Use Memory":false,"Deserialized":false,"Replication":1},"Barrier":false,"Number of Partitions":5,"Number of Cached Partitions":0,"Memory Size":0,"Disk Size":0},{"RDD ID":4,"Name":"/home/nick/Desktop/spatial-joins-polygons/AREALM.csv","Scope":"{\"id\":\"5\",\"name\":\"textFile\"}","Callsite":"textFile at WktReader.java:43","Parent IDs":[3],"Storage Level":{"Use Disk":false,"Use Memory":false,"Deserialized":false,"Replication":1},"Barrier":false,"Number of Partitions":5,"Number of Cached Partitions":0,"Memory Size":0,"Disk Size":0},{"RDD ID":5,"Name":"MapPartitionsRDD","Scope":"{\"id\":\"6\",\"name\":\"mapPartitions\"}","Callsite":"mapPartitions at RddReader.java:31","Parent IDs":[4],"Storage Level":{"Use Disk":false,"Use Memory":false,"Deserialized":false,"Replication":1},"Barrier":false,"Number of Partitions":5,"Number of Cached Partitions":0,"Memory Size":0,"Disk Size":0},{"RDD ID":3,"Name":"/home/nick/Desktop/spatial-joins-polygons/AREALM.csv","Scope":"{\"id\":\"5\",\"name\":\"textFile\"}","Callsite":"textFile at WktReader.java:43","Parent IDs":[],"Storage Level":{"Use Disk":false,"Use Memory":false,"Deserialized":false,"Replication":1},"Barrier":false,"Number of Partitions":5,"Number of Cached Partitions":0,"Memory Size":0,"Disk Size":0}],"Parent IDs":[],"Details":"org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.flatMapToPair(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)\norg.apache.sedona.core.spatialRDD.SpatialRDD.partition(SpatialRDD.java:325)\norg.apache.sedona.core.spatialRDD.SpatialRDD.spatialPartitioning(SpatialRDD.java:298)\ngr.ds..sedona.PolygonsJob.main(PolygonsJob.java:38)\njava.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\njava.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\njava.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\njava.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\norg.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)\norg.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:928)\norg.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)\norg.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)\norg.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)\norg.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1007)\norg.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1016)\norg.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)",,...}}}
{"Event":"SparkListenerStageSubmitted","Stage Info":{"Stage ID":4,"Stage Attempt ID":0,"Stage Name":"flatMapToPair at SpatialRDD.java:325","Number of Tasks":5,"RDD Info":[{"RDD ID":8,"Name":"MapPartitionsRDD","Scope":"{\"id\":\"19\",\"name\":\"flatMap\"}","Callsite":"flatMapToPair at SpatialRDD.java:325","Parent IDs":[2],"Storage Level":{"Use Disk":false,"Use Memory":false,"Deserialized":false,"Replication":1},"Barrier":false,"Number of Partitions":5,"Number of Cached Partitions":0,"Memory Size":0,"Disk Size":0},{"RDD ID":0,"Name":"/home/nick/Desktop/spatial-joins-polygons/AREALM.csv","Scope":"{\"id\":\"0\",\"name\":\"textFile\"}","Callsite":"textFile at WktReader.java:43","Parent IDs":[],"Storage Level":{"Use Disk":false,"Use Memory":false,"Deserialized":false,"Replication":1},"Barrier":false,"Number of Partitions":5,"Number of Cached Partitions":0,"Memory Size":0,"Disk Size":0},{"RDD ID":2,"Name":"MapPartitionsRDD","Scope":"{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"mapPartitions\"}","Callsite":"mapPartitions at RddReader.java:31","Parent IDs":[1],"Storage Level":{"Use Disk":false,"Use Memory":false,"Deserialized":false,"Replication":1},"Barrier":false,"Number of Partitions":5,"Number of Cached Partitions":0,"Memory Size":0,"Disk Size":0},{"RDD ID":1,"Name":"/home/nick/Desktop/spatial-joins-polygons/AREALM.csv","Scope":"{\"id\":\"0\",\"name\":\"textFile\"}","Callsite":"textFile at WktReader.java:43","Parent IDs":[0],"Storage Level":{"Use Disk":false,"Use Memory":false,"Deserialized":false,"Replication":1},"Barrier":false,"Number of Partitions":5,"Number of Cached Partitions":0,"Memory Size":0,"Disk Size":0}],"Parent IDs":[],"Details":"org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.flatMapToPair(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)\norg.apache.sedona.core.spatialRDD.SpatialRDD.partition(SpatialRDD.java:325)\norg.apache.sedona.core.spatialRDD.SpatialRDD.spatialPartitioning(SpatialRDD.java:287)\norg.apache.sedona.core.spatialRDD.SpatialRDD.spatialPartitioning(SpatialRDD.java:197)\ngr.ds..sedona.PolygonsJob.main(PolygonsJob.java:37)\njava.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\njava.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\njava.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\njava.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\norg.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)\norg.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:928)\norg.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)\norg.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)\norg.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)\norg.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1007)...}
{"Event":"SparkListenerStageSubmitted","Stage Info":{"Stage ID":5,"Stage Attempt ID":0,"Stage Name":"flatMapToPair at SpatialRDD.java:325","Number of Tasks":5,"RDD Info":[{"RDD ID":11,"Name":"MapPartitionsRDD","Scope":"{\"id\":\"22\",\"name\":\"flatMap\"}","Callsite":"flatMapToPair at SpatialRDD.java:325","Parent IDs":[5],"Storage Level":{"Use Disk":false,"Use Memory":false,"Deserialized":false,"Replication":1},"Barrier":false,"Number of Partitions":5,"Number of Cached Partitions":0,"Memory Size":0,"Disk Size":0},{"RDD ID":4,"Name":"/home/nick/Desktop/spatial-joins-polygons/AREALM.csv","Scope":"{\"id\":\"5\",\"name\":\"textFile\"}","Callsite":"textFile at WktReader.java:43","Parent IDs":[3],"Storage Level":{"Use Disk":false,"Use Memory":false,"Deserialized":false,"Replication":1},"Barrier":false,"Number of Partitions":5,"Number of Cached Partitions":0,"Memory Size":0,"Disk Size":0},{"RDD ID":5,"Name":"MapPartitionsRDD","Scope":"{\"id\":\"6\",\"name\":\"mapPartitions\"}","Callsite":"mapPartitions at RddReader.java:31","Parent IDs":[4],"Storage Level":{"Use Disk":false,"Use Memory":false,"Deserialized":false,"Replication":1},"Barrier":false,"Number of Partitions":5,"Number of Cached Partitions":0,"Memory Size":0,"Disk Size":0},{"RDD ID":3,"Name":"/home/nick/Desktop/spatial-joins-polygons/AREALM.csv","Scope":"{\"id\":\"5\",\"name\":\"textFile\"}","Callsite":"textFile at WktReader.java:43","Parent IDs":[],"Storage Level":{"Use Disk":false,"Use Memory":false,"Deserialized":false,"Replication":1},"Barrier":false,"Number of Partitions":5,"Number of Cached Partitions":0,"Memory Size":0,"Disk Size":0}],"Parent IDs":[],"Details":"org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.flatMapToPair(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)\norg.apache.sedona.core.spatialRDD.SpatialRDD.partition(SpatialRDD.java:325)\norg.apache.sedona.core.spatialRDD.SpatialRDD.spatialPartitioning(SpatialRDD.java:298)\ngr.ds..sedona.PolygonsJob.main(PolygonsJob.java:38)\njava.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\njava.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\njava.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\njava.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\norg.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)\norg.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:928)\norg.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)\norg.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)\norg.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)\norg.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1007)\norg.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1016)\norg.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)","Submission Time":1725739161810,"Accumulables":[]},"Properties":{}}
{"Event":"SparkListenerTaskStart","Stage ID":4,"Stage Attempt ID":0,"Task Info":{"Task ID":12,"Index":0,"Attempt":0,"Launch Time":1725739161808,"Executor ID":"driver","Host":"labis28.ted","Locality":"PROCESS_LOCAL","Speculative":false,"Getting Result Time":0,"Finish Time":0,"Failed":false,"Killed":false,"Accumulables":[]}}
...
{"Event":"SparkListenerTaskEnd","Stage ID":4,"Stage Attempt ID":0,"Task Type":"ShuffleMapTask","Task End Reason":{"Reason":"Success"},"Task Info":{"Task ID":16,"Index":4,"Attempt":0,"Launch Time":1725739164638,"Executor ID":"driver","Host":"labis28.ted","Locality":"PROCESS_LOCAL","Speculative":false,"Getting Result Time":0,"Finish Time":1725739164900,"Failed":false,"Killed":false,"Accumulables":[{"ID":126,"Name":"internal.metrics.input.recordsRead","Update":10897,"Value":129179,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":125,"Name":"internal.metrics.input.bytesRead","Update":12662624,"Value":147142496,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":124,"Name":"internal.metrics.shuffle.write.writeTime","Update":12787465,"Value":154760886,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":123,"Name":"internal.metrics.shuffle.write.recordsWritten","Update":10997,"Value":129697,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":122,"Name":"internal.metrics.shuffle.write.bytesWritten","Update":8638462,"Value":100458021,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":109,"Name":"internal.metrics.jvmGCTime","Update":7,"Value":74,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":108,"Name":"internal.metrics.resultSize","Update":1120,"Value":5600,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":107,"Name":"internal.metrics.executorCpuTime","Update":248419655,"Value":2978196111,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":106,"Name":"internal.metrics.executorRunTime","Update":256,"Value":3055,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":105,"Name":"internal.metrics.executorDeserializeCpuTime","Update":2567416,"Value":20999838,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":104,"Name":"internal.metrics.executorDeserializeTime","Update":2,"Value":19,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true}]},"Task Executor Metrics":{"JVMHeapMemory":0,"JVMOffHeapMemory":0,"OnHeapExecutionMemory":0,"OffHeapExecutionMemory":0,"OnHeapStorageMemory":0,"OffHeapStorageMemory":0,"OnHeapUnifiedMemory":0,"OffHeapUnifiedMemory":0,"DirectPoolMemory":0,"MappedPoolMemory":0,"ProcessTreeJVMVMemory":0,"ProcessTreeJVMRSSMemory":0,"ProcessTreePythonVMemory":0,"ProcessTreePythonRSSMemory":0,"ProcessTreeOtherVMemory":0,"ProcessTreeOtherRSSMemory":0,"MinorGCCount":0,"MinorGCTime":0,"MajorGCCount":0,"MajorGCTime":0},"Task Metrics":{"Executor Deserialize Time":2,"Executor Deserialize CPU Time":2567416,"Executor Run Time":256,"Executor CPU Time":248419655,"Peak Execution Memory":0,"Result Size":1120,"JVM GC Time":7,"Result Serialization Time":0,"Memory Bytes Spilled":0,"Disk Bytes Spilled":0,"Shuffle Read Metrics":{"Remote Blocks Fetched":0,"Local Blocks Fetched":0,"Fetch Wait Time":0,"Remote Bytes Read":0,"Remote Bytes Read To Disk":0,"Local Bytes Read":0,"Total Records Read":0},"Shuffle Write Metrics":{"Shuffle Bytes Written":8638462,"Shuffle Write Time":12787465,"Shuffle Records Written":10997},"Input Metrics":{"Bytes Read":12662624,"Records Read":10897},"Output Metrics":{"Bytes Written":0,"Records Written":0},"Updated Blocks":[]}}
{"Event":"SparkListenerStageCompleted","Stage Info":{"Stage ID":4,"Stage Attempt ID":0,"Stage Name":"flatMapToPair at SpatialRDD.java:325","Number of Tasks":5,"RDD Info":[{"RDD ID":8,"Name":"MapPartitionsRDD","Scope":"{\"id\":\"19\",\"name\":\"flatMap\"}","Callsite":"flatMapToPair at SpatialRDD.java:325","Parent IDs":[2],"Storage Level":{"Use Disk":false,"Use Memory":false,"Deserialized":false,"Replication":1},"Barrier":false,"Number of Partitions":5,"Number of Cached Partitions":0,"Memory Size":0,"Disk Size":0},{"RDD ID":0,"Name":"/home/nick/Desktop/spatial-joins-polygons/AREALM.csv","Scope":"{\"id\":\"0\",\"name\":\"textFile\"}","Callsite":"textFile at WktReader.java:43","Parent IDs":[],"Storage Level":{"Use Disk":false,"Use Memory":false,"Deserialized":false,"Replication":1},"Barrier":false,"Number of Partitions":5,"Number of Cached Partitions":0,"Memory Size":0,"Disk Size":0},{"RDD ID":2,"Name":"MapPartitionsRDD","Scope":"{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"mapPartitions\"}","Callsite":"mapPartitions at RddReader.java:31","Parent IDs":[1],"Storage Level":{"Use Disk":false,"Use Memory":false,"Deserialized":false,"Replication":1},"Barrier":false,"Number of Partitions":5,"Number of Cached Partitions":0,"Memory Size":0,"Disk Size":0},{"RDD ID":1,"Name":"/home/nick/Desktop/spatial-joins-polygons/AREALM.csv","Scope":"{\"id\":\"0\",\"name\":\"textFile\"}","Callsite":"textFile at WktReader.java:43","Parent IDs":[0],"Storage Level":{"Use Disk":false,"Use Memory":false,"Deserialized":false,"Replication":1},"Barrier":false,"Number of Partitions":5,"Number of Cached Partitions":0,"Memory Size":0,"Disk Size":0}],"Parent IDs":[],"Details":"org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.flatMapToPair(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)\norg.apache.sedona.core.spatialRDD.SpatialRDD.partition(SpatialRDD.java:325)\norg.apache.sedona.core.spatialRDD.SpatialRDD.spatialPartitioning(SpatialRDD.java:287)\norg.apache.sedona.core.spatialRDD.SpatialRDD.spatialPartitioning(SpatialRDD.java:197)\ngr.ds..sedona.PolygonsJob.main(PolygonsJob.java:37)\njava.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\njava.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\njava.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\njava.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\norg.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)\norg.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:928)\norg.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)\norg.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)\norg.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)\norg.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1007)\norg.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.ma...}}
{"Event":"SparkListenerTaskStart","Stage ID":5,"Stage Attempt ID":0,"Task Info":{"Task ID":18,"Index":1,"Attempt":0,"Launch Time":1725739165514,"Executor ID":"driver","Host":"labis28.ted","Locality":"PROCESS_LOCAL","Speculative":false,"Getting Result Time":0,"Finish Time":0,"Failed":false,"Killed":false,"Accumulables":[]}}
...
{"Event":"SparkListenerTaskEnd","Stage ID":5,"Stage Attempt ID":0,"Task Type":"ShuffleMapTask","Task End Reason":{"Reason":"Success"},"Task Info":{"Task ID":21,"Index":4,"Attempt":0,"Launch Time":1725739167543,"Executor ID":"driver","Host":"labis28.ted","Locality":"PROCESS_LOCAL","Speculative":false,"Getting Result Time":0,"Finish Time":1725739167799,"Failed":false,"Killed":false,"Accumulables":[{"ID":151,"Name":"internal.metrics.input.recordsRead","Update":10897,"Value":129179,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":150,"Name":"internal.metrics.input.bytesRead","Update":12662624,"Value":147142496,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":149,"Name":"internal.metrics.shuffle.write.writeTime","Update":12709203,"Value":136613382,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":148,"Name":"internal.metrics.shuffle.write.recordsWritten","Update":10997,"Value":129697,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":147,"Name":"internal.metrics.shuffle.write.bytesWritten","Update":8638462,"Value":100458021,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":134,"Name":"internal.metrics.jvmGCTime","Update":9,"Value":98,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":133,"Name":"internal.metrics.resultSize","Update":1120,"Value":5600,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":132,"Name":"internal.metrics.executorCpuTime","Update":243976276,"Value":2775206088,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":131,"Name":"internal.metrics.executorRunTime","Update":252,"Value":2873,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":130,"Name":"internal.metrics.executorDeserializeCpuTime","Update":2139317,"Value":14990671,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":129,"Name":"internal.metrics.executorDeserializeTime","Update":2,"Value":13,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true}]},"Task Executor Metrics":{"JVMHeapMemory":0,"JVMOffHeapMemory":0,"OnHeapExecutionMemory":0,"OffHeapExecutionMemory":0,"OnHeapStorageMemory":0,"OffHeapStorageMemory":0,"OnHeapUnifiedMemory":0,"OffHeapUnifiedMemory":0,"DirectPoolMemory":0,"MappedPoolMemory":0,"ProcessTreeJVMVMemory":0,"ProcessTreeJVMRSSMemory":0,"ProcessTreePythonVMemory":0,"ProcessTreePythonRSSMemory":0,"ProcessTreeOtherVMemory":0,"ProcessTreeOtherRSSMemory":0,"MinorGCCount":0,"MinorGCTime":0,"MajorGCCount":0,"MajorGCTime":0},"Task Metrics":{"Executor Deserialize Time":2,"Executor Deserialize CPU Time":2139317,"Executor Run Time":252,"Executor CPU Time":243976276,"Peak Execution Memory":0,"Result Size":1120,"JVM GC Time":9,"Result Serialization Time":0,"Memory Bytes Spilled":0,"Disk Bytes Spilled":0,"Shuffle Read Metrics":{"Remote Blocks Fetched":0,"Local Blocks Fetched":0,"Fetch Wait Time":0,"Remote Bytes Read":0,"Remote Bytes Read To Disk":0,"Local Bytes Read":0,"Total Records Read":0},"Shuffle Write Metrics":{"Shuffle Bytes Written":8638462,"Shuffle Write Time":12709203,"Shuffle Records Written":10997},"Input Metrics":{"Byt...}]}}
{"Event":"SparkListenerStageSubmitted","Stage Info":{"Stage ID":6,"Stage Attempt ID":0,"Stage Name":"count at PolygonsJob.java:42","Number of Tasks":28,"RDD Info":[{"RDD ID":17,"Name":"MapPartitionsRDD","Scope":"{\"id\":\"28\",\"name\":\"map\"}","Callsite":"mapToPair at JoinQuery.java:580","Parent IDs":[16],"Storage Level":{"Use Disk":false,"Use Memory":false,"Deserialized":false,"Replication":1},"Barrier":false,"Number of Partitions":28,"Number of Cached Partitions":0,"Memory Size":0,"Disk Size":0},{"RDD ID":9,"Name":"ShuffledRDD","Scope":"{\"id\":\"20\",\"name\":\"partitionBy\"}","Callsite":"partitionBy at SpatialRDD.java:335","Parent IDs":[8],"Storage Level":{"Use Disk":false,"Use Memory":false,"Deserialized":false,"Replication":1},"Barrier":false,"Number of Partitions":28,"Number of Cached Partitions":0,"Memory Size":0,"Disk Size":0},{"RDD ID":12,"Name":"ShuffledRDD","Scope":"{\"id\":\"23\",\"name\":\"partitionBy\"}","Callsite":"partitionBy at SpatialRDD.java:335","Parent IDs":[11],"Storage Level":{"Use Disk":false,"Use Memory":false,"Deserialized":false,"Replication":1},"Barrier":false,"Number of Partitions":28,"Number of Cached Partitions":0,"Memory Size":0,"Disk Size":0},{"RDD ID":14,"Name":"MapPartitionsRDD","Scope":"{\"id\":\"25\",\"name\":\"mapPartitions\"}","Callsite":"mapPartitions at SpatialRDD.java:416","Parent IDs":[13],"Storage Level":{"Use Disk":false,"Use Memory":false,"Deserialized":false,"Replication":1},"Barrier":false,"Number of Partitions":28,"Number of Cached Partitions":0,"Memory Size":0,"Disk Size":0},{"RDD ID":16,"Name":"MapPartitionsRDD","Scope":"{\"id\":\"27\",\"name\":\"mapPartitionsWithIndex\"}","Callsite":"mapPartitionsWithIndex at JoinQuery.java:579","Parent IDs":[15],"Storage Level":{"Use Disk":false,"Use Memory":false,"Deserialized":false,"Replication":1},"Barrier":false,"Number of Partitions":28,"Number of Cached Partitions":0,"Memory Size":0,"Disk Size":0},{"RDD ID":13,"Name":"MapPartitionsRDD","Scope":"{\"id\":\"24\",\"name\":\"mapPartitions\"}","Callsite":"mapPartitions at SpatialRDD.java:336","Parent IDs":[12],"Storage Level":{"Use Disk":false,"Use Memory":false,"Deserialized":false,"Replication":1},"Barrier":false,"Number of Partitions":28,"Number of Cached Partitions":0,"Memory Size":0,"Disk Size":0},{"RDD ID":15,"Name":"ZippedPartitionsRDD2","Scope":"{\"id\":\"26\",\"name\":\"zipPartitions\"}","Callsite":"zipPartitions at JoinQuery.java:554","Parent IDs":[10,14],"Storage Level":{"Use Disk":false,"Use Memory":false,"Deserialized":false,"Replication":1},"Barrier":false,"Number of Partitions":28,"Number of Cached Partitions":0,"Memory Size":0,"Disk Size":0},{"RDD ID":10,"Name":"MapPartitionsRDD","Scope":"{\"id\":\"21\",\"name\":\"mapPartitions\"}","Callsite":"mapPartitions at SpatialRDD.java:336","Parent IDs":[9],"Storage Level":{"Use Disk":false,"Use Memory":false,"Deserialized":false,"Replication":1},"Barrier":false,"Number of Partitions":28,"Number of Cached Partitions":0,"Memory Size":0,"Disk Size":0}],"Parent IDs":[5,4],"Detai...}
{"Event":"SparkListenerTaskStart","Stage ID":6,"Stage Attempt ID":0,"Task Info":{"Task ID":22,"Index":0,"Attempt":0,"Launch Time":1725739167817,"Executor ID":"driver","Host":"labis28.ted","Locality":"NODE_LOCAL","Speculative":false,"Getting Result Time":0,"Finish Time":0,"Failed":false,"Killed":false,"Accumulables":[]}}
...
{"Event":"SparkListenerTaskEnd","Stage ID":6,"Stage Attempt ID":0,"Task Type":"ResultTask","Task End Reason":{"Reason":"Success"},"Task Info":{"Task ID":49,"Index":24,"Attempt":0,"Launch Time":1725739253724,"Executor ID":"driver","Host":"labis28.ted","Locality":"PROCESS_LOCAL","Speculative":false,"Getting Result Time":0,"Finish Time":1725739253730,"Failed":false,"Killed":false,"Accumulables":[{"ID":101,"Name":"sedona.spatialjoin.streamCount","Update":"Map(24 -> 0)","Value":"Map(0 -> 2308, 5 -> 2015, 10 -> 2370, 24 -> 0, 25 -> 21, 14 -> 6065, 20 -> 18191, 1 -> 0, 6 -> 16277, 21 -> 0, 9 -> 15039, 13 -> 1, 2 -> 0, 17 -> 6557, 22 -> 10425, 27 -> 124, 12 -> 2382, 7 -> 0, 3 -> 3712, 18 -> 0, 16 -> 8155, 11 -> 11379, 26 -> 2353, 23 -> 0, 8 -> 6574, 19 -> 0, 4 -> 8168, 15 -> 7581)","Internal":false,"Count Failed Values":false},{"ID":102,"Name":"sedona.spatialjoin.resultCount","Update":"Map(24 -> 0)","Value":"Map(0 -> 3990, 5 -> 2547, 10 -> 3362, 24 -> 0, 25 -> 23, 14 -> 7039, 20 -> 20479, 1 -> 0, 6 -> 18183, 21 -> 0, 9 -> 16973, 13 -> 1, 2 -> 0, 17 -> 8547, 22 -> 11453, 27 -> 146, 12 -> 2708, 7 -> 0, 3 -> 4656, 18 -> 0, 16 -> 9821, 11 -> 12351, 26 -> 3201, 23 -> 0, 8 -> 9540, 19 -> 0, 4 -> 9470, 15 -> 8451)","Internal":false,"Count Failed Values":false},{"ID":103,"Name":"sedona.spatialjoin.candidateCount","Update":"Map(24 -> 0)","Value":"Map(0 -> 11708, 5 -> 2847, 10 -> 4384, 24 -> 0, 25 -> 27, 14 -> 7627, 20 -> 24273, 1 -> 0, 6 -> 19059, 21 -> 0, 9 -> 18475, 13 -> 1, 2 -> 0, 17 -> 10861, 22 -> 13227, 27 -> 260, 12 -> 2974, 7 -> 0, 3 -> 5620, 18 -> 0, 16 -> 10531, 11 -> 13827, 26 -> 4221, 23 -> 0, 8 -> 12788, 19 -> 0, 4 -> 10266, 15 -> 9365)","Internal":false,"Count Failed Values":false},{"ID":100,"Name":"sedona.spatialjoin.buildCount","Update":"Map(24 -> 0)","Value":"Map(24 -> 0, 1 -> 0, 21 -> 0, 2 -> 0, 7 -> 0, 18 -> 0, 23 -> 0, 19 -> 0)","Internal":false,"Count Failed Values":false},{"ID":171,"Name":"internal.metrics.shuffle.read.recordsRead","Update":0,"Value":259394,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":170,"Name":"internal.metrics.shuffle.read.fetchWaitTime","Update":0,"Value":0,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":169,"Name":"internal.metrics.shuffle.read.localBytesRead","Update":0,"Value":200916042,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":168,"Name":"internal.metrics.shuffle.read.remoteBytesReadToDisk","Update":0,"Value":0,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":167,"Name":"internal.metrics.shuffle.read.remoteBytesRead","Update":0,"Value":0,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":166,"Name":"internal.metrics.shuffle.read.localBlocksFetched","Update":0,"Value":112,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":165,"Name":"internal.metrics.shuffle.read.remoteBlocksFetched","Update":0,"Value":0,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":158,"Name":"internal.metrics.resultSize","Update":1905,"Value":54198,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":157,"Name":"internal.metrics.executorCpuTime","Update":2541708,"Value":84357285139,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":156,"Name":"internal...}}
{"Event":"SparkListenerStageCompleted","Stage Info":{"Stage ID":6,"Stage Attempt ID":0,"Stage Name":"count at PolygonsJob.java:42","Number of Tasks":28,"RDD Info":[{"RDD ID":17,"Name":"MapPartitionsRDD","Scope":"{\"id\":\"28\",\"name\":\"map\"}","Callsite":"mapToPair at JoinQuery.java:580","Parent IDs":[16],"Storage Level":{"Use Disk":false,"Use Memory":false,"Deserialized":false,"Replication":1},"Barrier":false,"Number of Partitions":28,"Number of Cached Partitions":0,"Memory Size":0,"Disk Size":0},{"RDD ID":9,"Name":"ShuffledRDD","Scope":"{\"id\":\"20\",\"name\":\"partitionBy\"}","Callsite":"partitionBy at SpatialRDD.java:335","Parent IDs":[8],"Storage Level":{"Use Disk":false,"Use Memory":false,"Deserialized":false,"Replication":1},"Barrier":false,"Number of Partitions":28,"Number of Cached Partitions":0,"Memory Size":0,"Disk Size":0},{"RDD ID":12,"Name":"ShuffledRDD","Scope":"{\"id\":\"23\",\"name\":\"partitionBy\"}","Callsite":"partitionBy at SpatialRDD.java:335","Parent IDs":[11],"Storage Level":{"Use Disk":false,"Use Memory":false,"Deserialized":false,"Replication":1},"Barrier":false,"Number of Partitions":28,"Number of Cached Partitions":0,"Memory Size":0,"Disk Size":0},{"RDD ID":14,"Name":"MapPartitionsRDD","Scope":"{\"id\":\"25\",\"name\":\"mapPartitions\"}","Callsite":"mapPartitions at SpatialRDD.java:416","Parent IDs":[13],"Storage Level":{"Use Disk":false,"Use Memory":false,"Deserialized":false,"Replication":1},"Barrier":false,"Number of Partitions":28,"Number of Cached Partitions":0,"Memory Size":0,"Disk Size":0},{"RDD ID":16,"Name":"MapPartitionsRDD","Scope":"{\"id\":\"27\",\"name\":\"mapPartitionsWithIndex\"}","Callsite":"mapPartitionsWithIndex at JoinQuery.java:579","Parent IDs":[15],"Storage Level":{"Use Disk":false,"Use Memory":false,"Deserialized":false,"Replication":1},"Barrier":false,"Number of Partitions":28,"Number of Cached Partitions":0,"Memory Size":0,"Disk Size":0},{"RDD ID":13,"Name":"MapPartitionsRDD","Scope":"{\"id\":\"24\",\"name\":\"mapPartitions\"}","Callsite":"mapPartitions at SpatialRDD.java:336","Parent IDs":[12],"Storage Level":{"Use Disk":false,"Use Memory":false,"Deserialized":false,"Replication":1},"Barrier":false,"Number of Partitions":28,"Number of Cached Partitions":0,"Memory Size":0,"Disk Size":0},{"RDD ID":15,"Name":"ZippedPartitionsRDD2","Scope":"{\"id\":\"26\",\"name\":\"zipPartitions\"}","Callsite":"zipPartitions at JoinQuery.java:554","Parent IDs":[10,14],"Storage Level":{"Use Disk"...}}
{"Event":"SparkListenerJobEnd","Job ID":4,"Completion Time":1725739253731,"Job Result":{"Result":"JobSucceeded"}}

